# Console.log messages do not appear in VSCode terminal window

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I'm doing an Electron tutorial using VSCode as my editor in Windows 10.

My main.js file contains only one line: console.log('main!');

When I open the terminal view (Ctrl+`) in VSCode and type "npm start" the console.log command does not display.

However, when I open a cmd.exe to and run "npm start" the "main!" console.log command appears.

I've tried changing the default terminal for VSCode to cmd.exe instead of powershell but had the same results.

What can I do to get my console.log command to appear in the VSCode terminal window?

Comment: Working fine on my machine. Does the start script in your package.json get executed? eg >electron .

Comment: Yeah. In package.json, under "scripts", I have an entry "start": "electron ."